# Banana and Bell Pepper Leaves curling with dark veins

Tags: vegetables, leaves, peppers

Recently I sprayed a mixture of dawn dish soap, water and cedar oil on my peppers because of aphids. Soon after there was a dramatic leaf drop. That appears to have stopped but the new leaves are curling with dark veins. What could cause this?

Comment: How much of each did you use? Can you add a picture? Did you spray when the sun was out?